# Accessing Text from Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I am having issues returning the text found through an xpath. First I needed to find the element through css selector:

```
ticker1 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-id="1"]')
print(ticker1.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

<div class="header_card"><div class="header_card_title">Day's Title<i class="fa fa-info-circle 
toolTrigger" data-title="Day's Title" data- 
id="DaysTitle-tooltip" data-model="what-is-this"></i></div><div 
class="header_card_trend_symbol headerTrend" data-title="" data-id="1" data-process="" 
data-categories="" data-datapoints=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down ph_trend_red"></i></div> 
<div class="header_card_metric_value" data-id="1"><span>$0</span></div></div><div 
class="header_bars_container"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
data-boundary="viewport" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa- 
bars optionsIconDropDown"></i></a><ul class="dropdown-menu drop-sm" style="position: relative; right: 
10px; top: -16px !important; "><li></li><li><a href="#" class="headerTrend" data-title="Prior Day's 
Production" data-id="1" data-open="" data-process="" data-categories="" data-datapoints="">Trend</a> 
</li></ul></div>
```

I then access the sub-element through xpath

```
t1l = ticker1.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='header_card_title']")
print(t1l.get_attribute('innerHTML'))

Day's Title<i class="fa fa-info-circle toolTrigger" data-title="Day's Title" 
data-id="PriorDaysProduction-tooltip" data-model="what-is-this"></i>
```

I have tried `.text`, `get_attribute('text')` , `get_attribute('values')` all return `''`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out,

it is `get_attribute('innerText')` although not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You were so close. Instead of `get_attribute('innerHTML')` you need to extract the *text* attribute as follows:

```
t1l = ticker1.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='header_card_title']")
print(t1l.text)
```

Ideally, to print the text **Day's Title** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
print(WebDriverWait(ticker1, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='header_card_title']"))).text)
```

You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: i tried `.text` and it didnt work, would return blank ' '.

Comment: @DannyCabrera Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.